# Switch designed to take #14 only

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I am using a 15 amp rated switch that only has 14 gauge stab in connections.  The house is wired with #12 with 20 amp breakers for the lighting circuits.  If I made #14 THHN whips that would stab into my switches and then connect to the #12 in the house would that meet code?

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/201207/what-are-backstab-receptacles-outlets

Answer (score 16):

### Back to the store it goes.

Switches which only take backstab connections are the cheapest of the builder/slumlord grade cheap.

Backstab connection, in general, are bad news - while *legal*, they are widely known to be unreliable.  They tend to knock out half your circuit and send you on a frustrating "bug hunt" - hang out here for a week and you'll see 2-3 such questions pop up.

**Further, backstab connections can only be used once** because pulling the wire out fatigues the spring.  I have a hunch this is a used one, and into the trash *that* goes!

New *builder-grade* switches are about 75 cents and have side screws.  New *spec-grade* switches are $3 and allow screw-to-clamp (2 wires under each screw; no backstab) which is safe to reuse.

### No part of a 20A circuit can be #14 wire.

None.  You simply need to use appropriate hardware. That ain't it.

You do not need to use the expensive 20A-rated switches, unless the load you are switching is actually that big :)

Comment: If switches had separate endurance and safety ratings, I could imagine allowing a switch with a 15A *endurance* rating to be used to switch a 15A or smaller load on a circuit with a 20A breaker, provided it was specified to be *safe* for use on such a circuit, with the caveat that intermittent currents between 15-40A or sustained currents over 20A may cause the switch to fail prematurely, but would not cause it to do anything dangerous like burst into flames.  Do switches rate such concepts separately?

Comment: Yes @supercat, switches are only required to interrupt the load they are driving.  So you don't need a "water heater grade" switch on a couple of sconces, but you might need it on 1800VA of workshop lighting.

Comment: Is there a requirement that a UL-listed switch, regardless of the amount of current it's rated to interrupt, must be safe for use on a circuit with an upstream circuit breaker of up to ___ amps without the switch itself catching fire or posing some other hazard, regardless of what's downstream of it?  If so, what would that value be?  I think normal practice for industrial controls would require that a 3A switch be guarded by a 3A fuse, but residential circuit breakers don't go down that low.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the back stabs, they are often the cause of failures. Use the screws on the side instead.  If the switch doesn't have screws, buy an other one that does.

**And NO, you can't use 14ga on a 20 amp circuit anywhere.**   Just get a high quality switch, it's your least expensive and best option.